# Run only one build pipeline task on a schedule

Tags: azure, triggers, continuous-integration, devops, pipeline

Is it possible to run only one build pipeline task on a schedule and not the whole pipeline on a schedule? I have a task in a build pipeline to generate some report about the pipeline. I would want the task to run once every month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. it is possible in several ways:

- you can set previously to the task the condition:

  ```
   ${{ if eq(variables['isBuild'], true) }}:
  ```
- You can configure conditions to run the tasks that you want, depending of whatever, for example in this case using the variable isBuild, defined previously:

  ```
   task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish artifact: drop'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: 'whatever'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
      condition: eq(variables['isBuild'], true)
  ```
- You can configure conditions to run the stages that you want, so previously you can group your tasks in stages, depending of whatever, for example using in this case in stage the variable isBuild, defined previously:

  ```
  stage: Build   
  displayName: 'Build'   
  condition: eq(variables['isBuild'], true)
  ```

In every example in case of IsBuild be different to true will not be run.

You can find more info in https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/pipelines/process/conditions.md

Also If you want to schedule your task to be executed only 1st day of every month at 07:00:

trigger:

- master  #This is the trigger for other stages. It is not needed for the scheduled stage.

  schedules:
  cron: '0 7 1 * *'

  ```
  displayName: 'Deploy every 1st day of every month at 07:00Z'

  branches:

    include:

     main

    always: true
  ```

Then to ensure that task runs as part of schedule, use the condition:

```
- stage: 'Test'
  
  displayName: 'Deploy to the test environment'

  dependsOn: Dev

  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
```

For more detail you can to to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am exploring the custom condition approach but not sure what the right expression should be for the task to run once a month. Any ideas?

Comment: To run once a month the best option is just to set a day and hour to do this deployment with the schedule...  in the next link you can see how to do it using azure dev tools https://faun.pub/run-an-azure-devops-pipeline-on-a-schedule-dd72b1c2b294

Answer (score 0):

Put the task in a second pipeline, and run that on a monthly schedule.

If you want to avoid yaml code duplication, you could define a template containing that one task and have that template called from both pipelines.

Comment: Thanks, I considered a second pipeline approach but I don't wish to use that solution. I was hoping I could run it from the same pipeline so maybe custom conditions will be ideal for the situation.

Comment: Hi Lin - can I ask _why_ you don't want to use a second pipeline?

Comment: I have a PS script task which takes build definitionID as an input, produces html report and  send to some distribution groups. The email goes to different parties based on the pipeline. The goal is to plug the task it in the various pipelines and use the arguments section to enumerate the recipients for each separate pipeline. The report is required once a month. By running through a second pipeline, I am assuming the definitionIDs for each of pipelines will have to be hardcoded. I am thinking that any change in a definition ID might break the process. I could be wrong.

Comment: It sounds like a change to the pipeline definition ID _would_ break your process, yes. I'd suggest restructuring your variables and your task, to separate the email distribution list from the pipeline ids; then you'd be able to make use of multiple pipelines more easily.